# How can I tell Mathematica create Heronian triangles in 2D like Maple'post?

Tags: computational-geometry

I see [this post](https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/208898-Heronian-Triangles-In-2D-Lattice) for the generation of triangles in a plane, for which the lengths of all sides, the area and radius of the inscribed circle are integers. In addition, all vertices must have different integer coordinates (6 different integers), the lengths of all sides are different and the triangles should not be rectangular.
I select one triangle.

```
Clear[a, b, c]
a = {2, 1};
b = {18, 31};
c = {30, 22};
EuclideanDistance[a, b]
EuclideanDistance[a, c]
EuclideanDistance[c, b]
mytriangle = Triangle[{a, b, c}];
Insphere[mytriangle]
Area@mytriangle
```

And tried

```
Clear[a, b, c]
pA = {0, 0};
pB = {c, 0};
pC = {(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/(2 c), 
   Sqrt[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c)]/(2 c)};
ss = Sqrt[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c)];
pp = a + b + c;
r = 2 ss/(a + b + c);
incenter = (a pA + b pB + c pC)/(a + b + c) // Simplify
list = Table[
   If[a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b && IntegerQ[a] && 
     IntegerQ[b] && IntegerQ[c] && GCD[a, b, c] == 1 && a < b < c && 
     a^2 + b^2 != c^2 && IntegerQ[(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/(2 c)] && 
     IntegerQ[Sqrt[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c)]/(
      2 c)] && IntegerQ[ss] && IntegerQ[r] && 
     IntegerQ[1/2  (-a + b + c)] && 
     IntegerQ[Sqrt[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c)]/(
      2 (a + b + c))], {pB, pC, incenter, a, b, c, pp, r, ss}, 
    Nothing], {a, 1, 100}, {b, 1, 100}, {c, 1, 100}];
Flatten[list, 2]
```

> {{{28, 0}, {20, 15}, {18, 6}, 17, 25, 28, 70, 24,
> 840}, {{36, 0}, {21, 20}, {20, 8}, 25, 29, 36, 90, 32,
> 1440}, {{56, 0}, {36, 15}, {35, 7}, 25, 39, 56, 120, 28,
> 1680}, {{63, 0}, {48, 20}, {45, 9}, 25, 52, 63, 140, 36,
> 2520}, {{55, 0}, {45, 24}, {40, 10}, 26, 51, 55, 132, 40,
> 2640}, {{48, 0}, {28, 21}, {27, 9}, 29, 35, 48, 112, 36,
> 2016}, {{66, 0}, {45, 28}, {42, 12}, 35, 53, 66, 154, 48,
> 3696}, {{96, 0}, {84, 35}, {75, 15}, 37, 91, 96, 224, 60,
> 6720}, {{77, 0}, {45, 24}, {44, 11}, 40, 51, 77, 168, 44,
> 3696}, {{75, 0}, {55, 48}, {48, 18}, 52, 73, 75, 200, 72,
> 7200}, {{88, 0}, {63, 60}, {55, 22}, 65, 87, 88, 240, 88,
> 10560}, {{77, 0}, {45, 60}, {42, 21}, 68, 75, 77, 220, 84, 9240}}

My code can not get the results that all vertices must have different integer coordinates (6 different integers) and it is difficult if $\{a, 1, 1000\}$, $\{b, 1, 1000\}$, $\{c, 1, 1000\}$.

How can I tell Mathematica creat Heronian triangles in 2D like maple'post?