How to get a triangle with so that centroid, orthocenter, center of circumcenter and center of incircle are integers
I want to create some triangle so that centroid, orthocenter, center of circumcenter and center of incircle are integers. I tried
Clear["Global`*"]

centroid[A_, B_, C0_] := (A + B + C0)/3

circumcenter[A_, B_, C0_] := 
 Module[{d, ux, uy}, 
  d = 2   (A[[1]]   (B[[2]] - C0[[2]]) + B[[1]]   (C0[[2]] - A[[2]]) +
       C0[[1]]   (A[[2]] - B[[2]]));
  ux = ((A[[1]]^2 + A[[2]]^2)   (B[[2]] - C0[[2]]) + (B[[1]]^2 + 
         B[[2]]^2)   (C0[[2]] - A[[2]]) + (C0[[1]]^2 + 
         C0[[2]]^2)   (A[[2]] - B[[2]]))/d;
  uy = ((A[[1]]^2 + A[[2]]^2)   (C0[[1]] - B[[1]]) + (B[[1]]^2 + 
         B[[2]]^2)   (A[[1]] - C0[[1]]) + (C0[[1]]^2 + 
         C0[[2]]^2)   (B[[1]] - A[[1]]))/d;
  {ux, uy}]

orthocenter[A_, B_, C0_] := A + B + C0 - 2  centroid[A, B, C0]

incenter[A_, B_, C0_] := Module[{a, b, c}, a = Norm[B - C0];
  b = Norm[C0 - A];
  c = Norm[A - B];
  (a   A + b   B + c   C0)/(a + b + c)]

isIntegerCoords[points_] := AllTrue[Flatten[points], IntegerQ]

results = 
  Reap[For[x1 = -10, x1 <= 10, x1++, 
    For[y1 = -10, y1 <= 10, y1++, 
     For[x2 = -10, x2 <= 10, x2++, 
      For[y2 = -10, y2 <= 10, y2++, 
       For[x3 = -10, x3 <= 10, x3++, 
        For[y3 = -10, y3 <= 10, y3++, A = {x1, y1}; B = {x2, y2};
         C0 = {x3, y3};
         cg = centroid[A, B, C0];
         cc = circumcenter[A, B, C0];
         oh = orthocenter[A, B, C0];
         ic = incenter[A, B, C0];
         
         If[isIntegerCoords[{cg, cc, oh, ic}], 
          Sow[{A, B, C0, cg, cc, oh, ic}]]]]]]]]];

Take[results[[2, 1]], 5]

For a long time, I don't get the results. How can I get the results?

Simply take an equilateral triangle and place it on a point with  integer coordinates.

Seems to be lots of potential interesting cases.  One in particular:  what is smallest  such that all of them are distinct integers?    What's smallest of each type of triangle to fit the criteria?  In a 10^7 grid, are there any?  And relevant to here, how can Mathematica find them most efficiently?  Parallizing?

See here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296690/how-can-i-tell-mathematica-create-heronian-triangles-in-2d-like-maplepost.

You might want to check: centroid and orthocenter calculate the same formula (centroid[A, B, C0] == orthocenter[A, B, C0] // Simplify yields True).

Pro tip: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica

@DanielHuber I think, you cann't find an equilateral triangle.

Maybe I misunderstand something. You are searching a triangle where all centers have integers coordinates. In an equilateral triangle all centers are at the same place.  E.g: pA = {0, 1};
pB = 1/2 {Sqrt[3], -1};
pC = 1/2 {-Sqrt[3], -1};

Have you tried using FindInstance[] instead?

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be three lengh of sides of the triangle. First, I find  incircle of the triangle
Clear["Global`*"];
    pA = {0, 0};
    pB = {c, 0};
    pC = {(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/(2  c), 
       Sqrt[(a + b - c)  (a - b + c)  (-a + b + c)  (a + b + c)]/(2  c)};
    ss = Sqrt[(a + b - c)  (a - b + c)  (-a + b + c)  (a + b + c)];
    pp = a + b + c;
    r = 2  ss/(a + b + c);
    incenter = (a  pA + b  pB + c  pC)/(a + b + c) // Simplify;
    list = Table[
       If[a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b && IntegerQ[a] && 
         IntegerQ[b] && IntegerQ[c] && GCD[a, b, c] == 1 && a < b < c && 
         a^2 + b^2 != c^2 && IntegerQ[(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/(2  c)] && 
         IntegerQ[
          Sqrt[(a + b - c)  (a - b + c)  (-a + b + c)  (a + b + 
               c)]/(2  c)] && IntegerQ[ss] && IntegerQ[r] && 
         IntegerQ[1/2   (-a + b + c)] && 
         IntegerQ[
          Sqrt[(a + b - c)  (a - b + c)  (-a + b + c)  (a + b + 
               c)]/(2  (a + b + c))], {pB, pC, incenter}, Nothing], {a, 1,100}, {b, 1, 100}, {c, 1, 100}];
    Flatten[list, 2]


Then, I consider the first triangle
Clear["Global`*"];
pA = {0, 0};
pB = {28, 0};
pC = {20, 15};
mytriangle = Triangle[{pA, pB, pC}];
myreg = RegionCentroid[mytriangle]
mycir = Circumsphere[mytriangle][[1]]
SolveValues[{x, y} - mycir == 3*(myreg - mycir), {x, y}][[1]]


Finaly,
Clear["Global`*"];
pA = {0, 0};
pB = 6 {28, 0}
pC = 6 {20, 15}
mytriangle = Triangle[{pA, pB, pC}];
myreg = RegionCentroid[mytriangle]
mycir = Circumsphere[mytriangle]
myins = Insphere[mytriangle]


